# Always use latest version of Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json.net, dependencies, nuget-package

I have a .NET project that has a reference to a nuget that depends on Newtonsoft.Json version 6.0.8. The nuget is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/3.0.2

I would like to only use the latest version of Newtonsoft in my project, so I want this project to actually use version 12.0 of Newtonsoft. I am unsure if this is possible. I tried adding an app.config file to my project, but that didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.1.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you really want that? What if they break something in the new build?

Comment: [Floating Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#floating-versions) are supported with the PackageReference element if you use the new project format that is used by default in .NET Core projects, .NET Standard projects, and UWP projects targeting Creators Update and later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

Comment: If I look under "Dependencies" on the Nuget page, I see that the recommended version for Newtonsoft is:
Newtonsoft.Json (>= 6.0.8)

So, 11 being >= 6.0.8, I resume it won't break anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my making the project explicitly reference the latest version of Newtonsoft. Everything seems to be working.

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
```